# writing values in a text file, getting run time check error

Tags: c

I'm programming in Windows 7, using MS Visual C++ 2010.

I am using an API that gives me access to error codes like this:

```
// iResult holds the error codes
lResult.GetCodeString()
```

I need to write this code in a text file. So here is how I proceeded:

```
char buff[10];

strcpy (buff, lResult.GetCodeString());

pFile_display = fopen ("D:\\ABCD\\myfile_display.txt","a+");
fputs("\nthe error vlaue returned is ", pFile_display ); 
fwrite (buff, sizeof(char), sizeof(buff), pFile_display);
```

Is there any better way of doing this, since I am getting runtime check error and I suspect I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a broken way of doing it.

1. You don't know how long the error message is, but you only reserve room for 10 characters. That's not a lot.
2. There's absolutely no need to copy the message into a second buffer before writing it into the file.
3. The use of `sizeof` to compute a string length is broken.
4. There's no need to use a low-level function intended for writing binary data (i.e., `fwrite()`) when your data is a string.

Just do:

```
fprintf(pFile_display, "The error is '%s'\n", lResult.GetCodeString());
```

By the way, [this random Google hit](https://github.com/ehsteve/SAAS/blob/master/ImperxStream.cpp) suggests that the return value of `GetCodeString()` perhaps isn't a C string. You should do:

```
fprintf(pFile_display, "The error is '%s'\n", lResult.GetCodeString().GetAscii());
```

to get the proper format. Of course you should be getting compiler warnings for this.

Comment: Thanks. BTW what do we mean by "broken"

Comment: @user3891236 I simply meant "not working", "not correct", "non-functioning" and so on. Code that doesn't work is often said to be broken.

Comment: I got this statement as teh output from your sprintf; The error return is '° ôZ\õZP!ôZ¤ÊôZlist<T> too long'
.what is wrong here ?

Comment: @user3891236 There is no `sprintf()`. You're supposed to use `fprintf()` to print directly to the file. Perhaps the string returned by `GetCodeString()` isn't a valid C string, after all?

Comment: sorry I meant fprintf only.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will update you tomorrow , as I will not have access to hardware till tomorrow morning.

Comment: asked another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750602/run-time-check-failure-2-while-using-api-for-saving-image-frame). kindly see this.