# Run-time check Failure #2 , while using API for saving image frame

Tags: c++, c

MSVS 2010 , Windows 7

I am using an API to access camera features.

The following function displays a frame and saves it.

```
void DisplayThread::OnBufferDisplay( PvBuffer *aBuffer )
{

       mDisplayWnd->Display( *aBuffer ); //displaying frame 


//Now let us try to save the frame with name of the form %Y%m%d%H%M%S.bmp

    system("mkdir D:\\ABCD" );  
            struct tm *tm;
            int count;
        time_t t;
        char str_time[20];
        t = time(NULL);
        tm = localtime(&t);
        strftime(str_time, sizeof(str_time), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S.bmp", tm); //name of the frame 
            char name[1000]; //sufficient space
         sprintf(name,"%s",str_time);
            char   path[]="D:\\ABCD";
            strcat(path,name); //path =path+"\\"+name;
        //  char* str=(char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(path);
    PvString lFilename( path );
                        PvString lCompleteFileName( lFilename );

 PvBufferWriter lBufferWriter; //The following function saves image
 PvResult lResult = lBufferWriter.Store( aBuffer, lCompleteFileName, PvBufferFormatBMP );


}
```

The name of the bmp file that is saved is of the form `%Y%m%d%H%M%S.bmp`

The program builds perfectly fine , even display is coming correctly, 
but the following error message pops up:

[image]

It looks like something is wrong with the memory allocation with the variable 'name'.

But I have allocated sufficient space, even then I am getting this error.

Why it is happening ?

Kindly let me know if more info is required to debug this.

**Note:** The value returned by lBufferWriter.Store() is 'OK' (indicating that buffer/frame writing was successful), but no file is getting saved. I guess this is because of the run-time check failure I am getting.

Please help.

Comment: `path` is too small, it can only hold 7 chars (+ zero terminator)

Comment: @Mat Can you please suggest then , what is the best practice ? shall I allocate an array char path[1000]  something like this?

Comment: Your buffer needs to be large enough to hold the data you're trying to put into it.  If you're on Windows, MAX_PATH is generally large enough for a filename.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks for your comment. Could you please give a small code snippet or modify my code to explain this , as an answer?   I will accept it as answer after verifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path[] array size is 8 and it is too small to hold the string after concatenation.
As this path variable is on the stack, it is corrupting your stack.
So, your buffer should be large enough to hold the data that you want to put into it.

In your case Just change the line to:

```
char path[1024]="D:\\ABCD";
```